# I wanted to know why the priorities aren't respected when using Math.Pow((11/3),2) in c#

Tags: c#, math

I wanted to know why when I try to do Math.Pow((11/3),2), it does the division first and then the exponent. Shouldn't it be the exponent first and then the division?
`Console.WriteLine(Math.Pow((11 / 3), 2));`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BE4fJ.png)
Thanks,

Comment: No there is a lot wrong with this, starting with it doesn't even work that way in math. Parentheses override any operator precedence. But `Pow` is a function call anyway. You will also soon find out what integer division is.

Comment: No. There are two reasons why it can't work the way you expect. a) BODMAS (although in this specific instance this is not making an impact). b) Even if BODMAS wasn't a thing, the parameters of a function are evaluated **then passed in to the function**. There is literally no way for `Pow` to execute _without knowing what its parameters are_. I don't think _any_ language works the way you are expecting. That plus you are using integer division, which you may or may not be doing on purpose.

Answer (score 4):

At no point does mathematical precedence get involved, because `Math.Pow` **is not a mathematical operator.** It is a method that is called with the result of evaluating the expressions that form its parameters.

The two parameters in this case are:

```
(11/3)
2
```

The first expression is an integer division with a result of `3`. So what you're doing is identical to `Math.Pow(3, 2)`.

Ultimately though this is about the difference between integer and floating point operations in code. Integer math is very, very different to floating point math, and the order of operations isn't the problem at all.

Let's change to a simple formula using only operators, no method calls:

```
int r1 = (11 / 3) * 3;
int r2 = 11 / 3 * 3;
```

Both of these give the same result due to operator precedence rules, and that answer is: `9`. Why?

Because the result of the integer division subexpression `11/3` is `3`. The program you've written has no way to evaluate the wider expression to find a "more accurate" result, because that's not what you've chosen to tell it to do. At no point is it going to do some broader evaluation of the expression to try to run it through a bunch of transformations like you did in the image you posted. In integer math `(11 / 3) * 3` is never going to be evaluated as some variation of `33 / 9` *unless you write it that way.*

Going back to your `Math.Pow` example, even if we had a power operator (which we don't in C#) it's still not going to perform arithmetic transformations to compute the result.

Let's imagine a hypothetical `**` operator that performs exponentiation such that the following is a valid expression:

```
int result = (11 / 3) ** 2;
```

By precedence rules, the bracketed sub-expression is evaluated first giving us the integer value `3`. That is passed as the left operand to the exponentiation operator, giving us `3 ** 2` for a result of `9`.

Because that's how **all** math works in computing. The compiler is never, ever going to use arithmetic transforms to work out an answer, it just performs the requested operations on the values of the operands. If you want something else then you have to tell it exactly what you want it to do.

Comment: @mjwills That was a different equation to just show how a valid C# expression will still give (potentially) unexpected results. Intuitively `(11 / 3) * 3` looks like it should result in `11`, but integer evaluation gives us `9` instead.